# Finding asymptotes for $f(x)=\frac{x^2+3x-10}{3x^2+13x-10}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2+3x-10}{3x^2+13x-10}$$

I know that the horizontal asymptote is $1/3$. To find the vertical asymptotes, I set the denominator equal to zero and used the quadratic formula, and I got $-5$ and $2/3$, and this is wrong.

How do you find the vertical asymptotes for this problem? 
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$3x^2 + 13x - 10 = (3x - 2)(x + 5)$, and $x^2 + 3x - 10 = (x + 5)(x - 3)$. Thus only $x = \dfrac{2}{3}$ is the vertical asymptote since $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -5} f(x) = \dfrac{8}{17} \neq \infty$

Comment: Therefore given function is same as $\dfrac{x-3}{3x-2}$ for any real $x$ not equal to $2/3$ or$5.$

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$f(x)=\frac{(x+5)(x-2)}{(x+5)(3x-2)}.$$

Therefore
$$\lim_{x\to-5} f(x) = \lim_{x\to-5}\frac{(x+5)(x-2)}{(x+5)(3x-2)} =\lim_{x\to-5}\frac{x-2}{3x-2} = \frac{7}{17}.$$

Since this limit is actually not infinite, there is no vertical asymptote when $x=-5$.

In general, vertical asymptotes of a rational function occur at $x=a$ provided that the largest power of $(x-a)$ dividing the denominator is greater than that of the numerator. Here, $(x+5)$ divided the numerator and the denominator exactly once, so there was no asymptote when $x=-5$.